# Porting Java Enumerator to C#

Tags: c#, java, enums, porting

I have a Java enumerator shortened to the following from the BioJava library:

```
public enum Element implements Serializable {

// most frequently used elements first
H(1, 1, 39, 1.10f, 0.32f, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.008f, 0, 1, 2.20f, ElementType.OTHER_NONMETAL),
C(6, 2, 0, 1.55f, 0.77f, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 12.011f, 2, -4, 2.55f, ElementType.OTHER_NONMETAL),
N(7, 2, 57, 1.40f, 0.75f, 5, 2, 5, 3, 4, 14.007f, 2, -3, 3.04f, ElementType.OTHER_NONMETAL),
O(8, 2, 65, 1.35f, 0.73f, 6, 1, 2, 2, 2, 16.000f, 2, -2, 3.44f, ElementType.OTHER_NONMETAL),
.....


private int atomicNumber;
private int period;
private float VDWRadius; // in Angstroms
private float covalentRadius; // in Angstroms
private int valenceElectronCount;
private int minimumValence;
private int maximumValence;
private int commonValence;
private int maximumCovalentValence;
private float atomicMass;
private int coreElectronCount;
private int oxidationState;
private float paulingElectronegativity;
private ElementType elementType;


private static final Map<String,Element> allElements ;

static {
    allElements = new HashMap<String,Element>();
    for (Element e : Element.values()){
        allElements.put(e.toString().toLowerCase(), e);
    }
}
private Element(int atomicNumber,
        int period,
        int hillOrder,
        float VDWRadius,
        float covalentRadius,
        int valenceElectronCount,
        int minimumValence,
        int maximumValence,
        int commonValence,
        int maximumCovalentValence,
        float atomicMass,
        int coreElectronCount,
        int oxidationState,
        float paulingElectronegativity,
        ElementType elementType) {

    this.atomicNumber = atomicNumber;
    this.period = period;
    //this.hillOrder = hillOrder;
    this.VDWRadius = VDWRadius;
    this.covalentRadius = covalentRadius;
    this.valenceElectronCount = valenceElectronCount;
    this.minimumValence = minimumValence;
    this.maximumValence = maximumValence;
    this.commonValence = commonValence;
    this.maximumCovalentValence = maximumCovalentValence;
    this.atomicMass = atomicMass;
    this.coreElectronCount = coreElectronCount;
    this.oxidationState = oxidationState;
    this.paulingElectronegativity = paulingElectronegativity;
    this.elementType = elementType;


}
```

I would like to simply port this structure to C#, where there is an enumeration of the elements with the basic information of the Element attached.  How would I do this?

Preferably, the solution would be memory efficient.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to use C# collections?

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, StackOverflow is not a free code conversion service. Are there any specific issues you're having with *your* implementation?

Comment: Hey guys, I wasn't intending to use StackOverflow as a code converting source.  C# enumerators and Java enumerators are two very different things, and I wasn't sure how to generalise a Java enumerator for C#.  I wasn't even sure where to begin.

Comment: My post has now been downvoted and put on hold and stuff.

Fair enough.  If I have a question like this, being new to a language and trying to get an answer to a question I can't seem to find in my texts, where should I go with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Enumerations in the CLR are simply named constants. The underlying
>   type must be integral. In Java an enumeration is more like a named
>   instance of a type. That type can be quite complex and - as your
>   example shows - contain multiple fields of various types.
>
> To port the example to C# I would just change the enum to an immutable
>   class and expose static readonly instances of that class:

```
public class Element {

    // most frequently used elements first
    public static readonly Element H = new Element(1, 1, 39, 1.10f, 0.32f, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.008f, 0, 1, 2.20f, ElementType.OTHER_NONMETAL);
    public static readonly Element C = new Element(6, 2, 0, 1.55f, 0.77f, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 12.011f, 2, -4, 2.55f, ElementType.OTHER_NONMETAL);
    public static readonly Element N = new Element(7, 2, 57, 1.40f, 0.75f, 5, 2, 5, 3, 4, 14.007f, 2, -3, 3.04f, ElementType.OTHER_NONMETAL);
    public static readonly Element O = new Element(8, 2, 65, 1.35f, 0.73f, 6, 1, 2, 2, 2, 16.000f, 2, -2, 3.44f, ElementType.OTHER_NONMETAL);



    private int atomicNumber;
    private int period;
    private float VDWRadius; // in Angstroms
    private float covalentRadius; // in Angstroms
    private int valenceElectronCount;
    private int minimumValence;
    private int maximumValence;
    private int commonValence;
    private int maximumCovalentValence;
    private float atomicMass;
    private int coreElectronCount;
    private int oxidationState;
    private float paulingElectronegativity;
    private ElementType elementType;


    private static readonly IDictionary<String,Element> allElements ;

    static Element(){
        allElements = new Dictionary<String,Element>();
        allElements.Add("h", H);
        allElements.Add("c", C);
        allElements.Add("n", N);
        allElements.Add("o", O);
    }
    private Element(int atomicNumber,
            int period,
            int hillOrder,
            float VDWRadius,
            float covalentRadius,
            int valenceElectronCount,
            int minimumValence,
            int maximumValence,
            int commonValence,
            int maximumCovalentValence,
            float atomicMass,
            int coreElectronCount,
            int oxidationState,
            float paulingElectronegativity,
            ElementType elementType) {

        this.atomicNumber = atomicNumber;
        this.period = period;
        //this.hillOrder = hillOrder;
        this.VDWRadius = VDWRadius;
        this.covalentRadius = covalentRadius;
        this.valenceElectronCount = valenceElectronCount;
        this.minimumValence = minimumValence;
        this.maximumValence = maximumValence;
        this.commonValence = commonValence;
        this.maximumCovalentValence = maximumCovalentValence;
        this.atomicMass = atomicMass;
        this.coreElectronCount = coreElectronCount;
        this.oxidationState = oxidationState;
        this.paulingElectronegativity = paulingElectronegativity;
        this.elementType = elementType;


    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  When this structure is used, a new instance of an Element object will be generated, yes?  Is there a way in C# for such a list of constant values for an object to be in a central dictionary rather than attached to every instance of the object (other than making a random dictionary that will need to be instantiated at the beginning and then used for lookups through calls to the dictionary and not through the object)?  (or if that is how this code will operate, please forgive me for misunderstanding the code)

Comment: With this example: Only 4 instances of `Element` are instanciated (because they are `static`). You can't create other instances (because the only constructor is private). You can't access `allElements` because it's private. Why would you save all elements? Maybe you want it to be `public`?

Comment: So with this structure, I now have all of the elements listed.  I'm not entirely sure what should be made public, though.  What I want is to be able to access element values with a call similar to: Element.H.covalentRadius.  With the current rendition, I cannot access the individual elements in this manner (though I've made all of their properties public so that their members should be available).  How do I access the individual elements in this construct?

(I'm sorry again for being a C# noob.  It's being surprisingly difficult to get used to from F#.)

Comment: Change the attributes to public properties : `public int AtomicNumber {get; private set;}`

Comment: Also make allElements public to be able to access it from the outside: `public static IDictionary<String, Element> AllElements { get; private set; }`